# JPA Query : How to check IS NULL or IS NOT NULL?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have below parameter which is

```
Boolean isActive = true/false
```

I need to pass this parameter in JPA Query.

```
true =  IS NOT NULL
false = IS NULL

@Query("select t from Test t WHERE t.active = ?1")
Optional<Test> findByIds(Boolean isActive);
```

How can I achieve this, rather than creating 2 separate queries for IS NULL & IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following way

```
@Query("select t from Test t WHERE (?1 = true AND t.active IS NOT NULL) OR
                                   (?1 = false AND t.active IS NULL")
Optional<Test> findByIds(Boolean isActive);
```